# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="xyz"'

Tags: iis, .net-core

We have a web application (netcore) configured to use Windows authentication it was working fine, but now we dont know why iis sends basic authentication header even it is has configured windows authentication.

Any idea why?

Comment: It doesn't matter, as long as the user didn't pass the authentication. Basic authentication requires the window credential too, such as domain, user, password. It authenticates the client user with server Windows account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer to myself, the error was related to a blocked user.